# Information retrieval problem

Tags: research, search-engine

I am doing some work on emotions and the web. To do this I need some data on search queries that relate to the user's emotion. For example songs. Can anyone give me a source for this kind of data?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation of the [Twitter Search API for tweets](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search) mentions operators, such as ":)", where you can specify whether the tweet has a positive or a negative attitude. You can combine this with the operator that asks for tweets that contains questions ("?"), and with any other operator such as hashtag search, e.g. [#London](https://twitter.com/search?f=tweets&vertical=default&q=%23London%20%3F%20%3A%29&src=typd), or  [#song](https://twitter.com/search?q=%23song%20%3F%20%3A%29&src=typd)